# Tkinter askdirectory() not showing on screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to allow a user to choose the directory where they want to save a file to, however anytime I call a Tkinkter function AFTER the initial `askopenfilename()`, it just hangs. `askopenfilename()` works the first time it's called but that and `askdirectory()` won't work anytime after. This is just me messing around with Tkinter as I'm new to it. The Pandas stuff all works fine and no error is being shown; Tkinter just hangs after it reaches line 21 (`saved = askdirectory()`).

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfile, askopenfilename

excelArray = ["excel", "xlsx", "xl", "x", "exsel", "ex", "e"]
consoleArray = ["console", "c", "concole", "con", "consle"]

root=Tk()
root.withdraw()

pathToExcel = askopenfilename()
print(f"\nOpening the excel document located at: {pathToExcel}")

userOutput = input("\nWhere would you like the output to be? Console or Excel?").lower()
if userOutput in excelArray:
    print("Where would you like to save it?")
    saved = askdirectory()
    print("Saved")
else:
    print("\n")
    print(test[['1', '2', '3']])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hang"? The code has an `input` statement, so it's going to wait for you to type something in the console. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Could you please make a [mre] from this? If the pandas stuff works fine, you could remove it from the code. That makes your question shorter, and others don't have to install pandas to test your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Once the input 'excel' is passed and it goes through the if statement, the askdirectory() doesn't ever pop up with a modal and I can't type in or end the script.

Comment: @wovano It should be without the pandas stuff now. Also did it end up launching the askdirectory()? I couldn't get it to do that at all.

Comment: The second dialog popped up for me on OSX.  What platform are you running on?

Comment: Yes, worked for me. Got the "open file" dialog, then the question on the console, then (if I typed "excel" of course) the directory dialog. Really strange if the same code doesn't work for you. Did you already try it without the `input()`? Please reduce your code to the **bare minimum** which still reproduces your problem. And it might be useful to mention your OS amd Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the program hangs when the root is withdrawn. From your code, remove the following things:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

So the final code will be:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfile, askopenfilename

excelArray = ["excel", "xlsx", "xl", "x", "exsel", "ex", "e"]
consoleArray = ["console", "c", "concole", "con", "consle"]

pathToExcel = askopenfilename()
print(f"\nOpening the excel document located at: {pathToExcel}")

userOutput = input("\nWhere would you like the output to be? Console or Excel?").lower()
if userOutput in excelArray:
    print("Where would you like to save it?")
    saved = askdirectory()
    print("Saved")
else:
    print("\n")
    print(test[['1', '2', '3']])
```

Comment: With the code that I have given, I get both. The _Where would you like to save it?_ message and the ```askdirectory()``` popup. When I select the folder, it says _Saved_ and exits

Comment: Yes! This is the solution; it seems like the best possible solution for the issue! That blank Tkinter window that opens is an annoying visual that I was hoping the ```withdraw()``` would fix but I see it just ended up making the code hang entirely. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NicoF. I'm glad this works for you. However, could you still add in your question which OS and Python version you are using? I'm curious why some people have this problem and some people don't. This information might help future readers with the same problem.

Comment: @NicoF Glad that helped!